# R draw heatmap with clusters, but hide dendrogram

Tags: r, plot, visualization, heatmap

By default, R's `heatmap` will cluster rows and columns:

```
mtscaled = as.matrix(scale(mtcars))
heatmap(mtscaled, scale='none')
```

[image]

I can disable the clustering:

```
heatmap(mtscaled, Colv=NA, Rowv=NA, scale='none')
```

And then the dendrogram goes away:[image]

But now the data is not clustered anymore.

I don't want the dendrograms to be shown, but I still want the rows and/or columns to be clustered. How can I do this?

Example of what I want:[image]

Comment: Help to close the below one as recommended answer - if it solves your problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
library(gplots)
heatmap.2(mtscaled,dendrogram='none', Rowv=TRUE, Colv=TRUE,trace='none')
```

`Rowv` -is TRUE, which implies dendrogram is computed and reordered based on row means.

`Colv` - columns should be treated identically to the rows.

[image]

Comment: gplots fails to load for R 3.5.2, as it cannot load the dependency caTools, nor is that dependency available from the CRAN repository.

Answer (score 16):

You can do this with [pheatmap](https://github.com/raivokolde/pheatmap):

```
mtscaled <- as.matrix(scale(mtcars))
pheatmap::pheatmap(mtscaled, treeheight_row = 0, treeheight_col = 0)
```

See pheatmap output here:

[image: pheatmap output]

Comment: `pheatmap` clusters by default (`cluster_rows = TRUE,
  cluster_cols = TRUE`)

Answer (score 3):

You can rely on base R structures and consider following approach based on building the hclust trees by yourself.

```
mtscaled = as.matrix(scale(mtcars))
row_order = hclust(dist(mtscaled))$order
column_order = hclust(dist(t(mtscaled)))$order
heatmap(mtscaled[row_order,column_order], Colv=NA, Rowv=NA, scale="none")
```

No need to install additional junk.

Answer (score 2):

For ComplexHeatmap, there are function parameters to remove the dendrograms:

```
library(ComplexHeatmap)
Heatmap(as.matrix(iris[,1:4]), name = "mat", show_column_dend = FALSE, show_row_dend = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue with pheatmap, which has better visualisation and heatmap or heatmap.2. Though heatmap.2 is a choice for your solution, Here is the solution with pheatmap, by extracting the order of clustered data.

```
library(pheatmap)
mtscaled = as.matrix(scale(mtcars))
H = pheatmap(mtscaled)
```

[Here is the output of pheatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1grjY.png)

```
pheatmap(mtscaled[H$tree_row$order,H$tree_col$order],cluster_rows = F,cluster_cols = F)
```

[Here is the output of pheatmap after extracting the order of clusters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wibN3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Do the dendrogram twice using the basic R heatmap function. Take the output of the first run, which clusters but has mandatory drawing of the dendrogram and feed it into the heatmap function again. This time, without clustering, and without drawing the dendrogram.

#generate a random symmetrical matrix with a little bit of structure, and make a heatmap

```
M100s<-matrix(runif(10000),nrow=100)
M100s[2,]<-runif(100,min=0.1,max=0.2)
M100s[4,]<-runif(100,min=0.1,max=0.2)
M100s[6,]<-runif(100,min=0.1,max=0.2)
M100s[99,]<-runif(100,min=0.1,max=0.2)
M100s[37,]<-runif(100,min=0.1,max=0.2)
M100s[lower.tri(M100s)] <- t(M100s)[lower.tri(M100s)]
heatmap(M100s)
```

#save the output

```
OutputH <- heatmap(M100s)
```

#run it again without clustering or the dendrogram

```
M100c <- M100s
M100c1 <- M100c[,OutputH$rowInd]
M100c2 <- M100c1[OutputH$colInd,]
heatmap(M100c2,Rowv = NA, Colv = NA, labRow = NA, labCol = NA)
```