# Is there a way to create a heatmap of multiple values for the same compared variables – essentially a heatmap within a heatmap?

Tags: r, plot, graph, heatmap

Hi I am new to R and trying to learn. I would like to compare the overlap of 4 clusters which have the same 4 categories each in them. Basically, I am thinking of making a clustered heatmap like this image below that I quickly made as an example in excel. Does anyone know of an R package that would allow me to make a graph like this? So far, I have only found packages that limit you to one variable per X vs Y variable grid space. Thanks so much for your suggestions!

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: You can create clustered heatmaps in r through many packages including `ggplot2` and `pheatmap`. This post might be helpful  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29893630/r-draw-heatmap-with-clusters-but-hide-dendrogram but it's not 100% clear exactly what you want in terms of the numbers of variables.